# After changing the site root, how to reflect this for wp-admin too?

Tags: urls

My website file structure is like this:

```
index.php
wp/wp files ...
```

In general in Site Address (URL) I have ...site.com

In index.php I have:

```
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
    require('./wp/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Everything works fine but for wp-admin i have ...site.com/wp/wp-admin/

My question is: Can I change the url for wp-admin also to have ...site.com/wp-admin/?

Comment: As in move the location of wp-admin, or as in rewrite the URL?

Comment: wp-admin is at wp/wp-admin and I want to remove from url the wp/ part. I am happy with a rewrite rule also just to not be hard coded with website name.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to regex it with `/wp/(wp-admin/.*)` and point that to `/$1`, thus removing the /wp/.  You can do this either via `.htaccess` or via wordpress' rewrite API.

Answer (score 0):

if you're happy with a rewrite rule:

in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule   ^wp/(.+)$   $1   [nocase,redirect=temp,last]
```

if might work without the [redirect] flag.

if you want to be very specific:

```
RewriteRule   ^wp/(wp-admin/.*)$   $1   [nocase,redirect=temp,last]
```

within WP (the rewrite will need to happen before permalink rewrites, etc):

```
add_action( 'init', 'gregory_rewrite_wpadmin' );
function gregory_rewrite_wpadmin()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^wp/(wp-admin/.*)$',
        '$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

not tested, but trying it won't hurt you ;-)

cheers,
Gregory